# Binary format and bit format

Tags: binary, bit

how to you know what code format is..?

Is this below code is Binary or bit? and how to convert in any other format or number decimal format

**01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F 00 00 80 3F**

Comment: What do you mean by "bit format"?

Comment: Without context, it's virtually impossible to tell. Where did you get this data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary means that you have two possible states (base 2). 1 and 0.

Something that bears that atomic information is usually referred to as a bit.

What you see there are hexadecimal numbers. (base 16)

This notation is often used to display binary data in a more compact form.

The decimal number `255` can be written as `11111111` (binary) or `FF` (hex)
So each pair is one byte. What they mean depends on where you got those numbers from.

Comment: Got ya.. itz a Array Binary base 16 !